# Server side paging for MVC3 Webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, webgrid

I have looked at a number of examples (e.g. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=618 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650669.aspx) but it seems very manual and convoluted.

The reason I would like to use the WebGrid is that there are no external dependancies, but I have very succesfully used jqGrid on another project.

Has anyone else succesfully managed to get server side paging working on the MVC3 Webgrid and would you recommend I use that rather than the jqGrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650669.aspx) illustrates a perfect example of how to achieve server side paging. No matter which grid you use on the client, on the server that's a good way to paginate your data. As far as the `WebGrid` helper is concerned, I would recommend you [MvcContrib.Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid&ProjectName=mvccontrib) or [Telerik Grid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/grid.aspx) if you are looking for a server side grid. If you are looking for a client side grid, jqGrid is really nice.

You might find some commercial components for which the server side code doesn't look *convoluted* to you but bear in mind that with such solutions you don't know how what is happening under the covers, even worse you might lose control, which usually ends up with late night calls from your db administrators telling you that your queries are just a horror.

Comment: That was one of the articles I mentioned in my question.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: I've actually decided to use jqGrid - mainly because of the jquery.ui themes that are available - and the obvious built in paging, sorting etc (I already had the server side MVC code available) - looks great and I'm very happy with the solution